# JBoss EAP 7(beta) isn't finding tomcat jars

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss

I'm trying to transfer a war from glassfish to jboss. It seems to work fine on deployment, so long as I comment out two servlets in the web.xml which really shouldn't be a problem:

```
org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet
org.apache.catalina.servlets.CGIServlet
```

Both of these are in the jboss docs so I assume they should work, and I assumed they would just be copied over from Tomcat, but I get:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet
```

and the same for the CGIServlet when they're not commented out.

Is there some special trick to using these in JBoss or some intended alternative?

Comment: The eap7 uses undertow instead of tomcat so you might consider adapting your code according to the undertow api

Answer (score 1):

I found this out on my own, but janinee answered it in the comment to my original post, so I'll give it to him:

The eap7 uses undertow instead of tomcat so you might consider adapting your code according to the undertow api